# Running shell commands within python interpreter

Tags: python, bash, interpreter

Is there a simple method for calling shell command line arguments (like ls or pwd) from within python interpreter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain python, you need to use something along the lines of this:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("ls", shell=True)
```

In IPython, you can run either of those commands or a general shell command by starting off with `!`.  For example

```
! echo "Hello, world!" > /tmp/Hello.txt
```

If you're using python interactively, you would almost certainly be happier with [IPython](http://ipython.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to use the Python shell interactively while being able to call commands (ls, pwd, ...) check out iPython.